# How to install botocore in yocto

Tags: python, boto3, yocto, botocore

I need boto3 in yocto and I cannot find a recipe that install botocore.

I have found the recipe for boto3, see below, but the boto3-xxx.tar.gz installs botocore through requirements.txt. Yocto does not seems to run it.

Finally, boto3 is installed but it is completely missing botocore.

```
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/boto/boto"
SUMMARY = "Amazon Web Services API"
DESCRIPTION = "\
  Boto3 is the Amazon Web Services (AWS) Software Development Kit (SDK) for Python, \
  which allows Python developers to write software that makes use of services like \
  Amazon S3 and Amazon EC2. \
  "
SECTION = "devel/python"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=2ee41112a44fe7014dce33e26468ba93"


SRCNAME = "boto3"
SRC_URI = "https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/b/${SRCNAME}/${SRCNAME}-${PV}.tar.gz"


SRC_URI[md5sum] = "fb8b77d4ac10a971570419dd3613196e"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "4856c8cb4150b900cc7dccbdf16f542fb8c12e97b17639979e58760847f7cf35"

inherit pypi setuptools3
```

[image]

Regards
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good practice when coming to Yocto python recipes is to use [pipoe](https://pypi.org/project/pipoe/)

Running pipoe for boto3 creates boto3 recipe with its dependencies recipes:

pipoe -p boto3 --python python3

Output:

- python3-boto3_1.17.98.bb
- python3-botocore_1.20.98.bb
- python3-jmespath_0.10.0.bb
- python3-s3transfer_0.4.2.bb

**python3-boto3_1.17.98.bb:**

```
SUMMARY = "The AWS SDK for Python"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/boto/boto3"
AUTHOR = "Amazon Web Services <>"
LICENSE = "Apache-2.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=2ee41112a44fe7014dce33e26468ba93"

SRC_URI = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cd/16/90930985c3f2db2a8d412f6f05b68c80ee7417d8a630c27f94bb032131c1/boto3-1.17.98.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "89b046023f1d05e4c2573fad5ea6c020"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "fccfa81cda69bb2317ed97e7149d7d84d19e6ec3bfbe3f721139e7ac0c407c73"

S = "${WORKDIR}/boto3-1.17.98"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "python3-botocore python3-jmespath python3-s3transfer"

inherit setuptools3
```

**python3-botocore_1.20.98.bb:**

```
SUMMARY = "Low-level, data-driven core of boto 3."
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/boto/botocore"
AUTHOR = "Amazon Web Services <>"
LICENSE = "Apache-2.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE.txt;md5=2ee41112a44fe7014dce33e26468ba93"

SRC_URI = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/f4/3dc9e36d0b73341f14a5112561f7540fd76f0a692c7dcc83a3be5d7436de/botocore-1.20.98.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "05798450904b0d3d8fa5db24e2208e85"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "b2a49de4ee04b690142c8e7240f0f5758e3f7673dd39cf398efe893bf5e11c3f"

S = "${WORKDIR}/botocore-1.20.98"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = ""

inherit setuptools3
```

**python3-jmespath_0.10.0.bb:**

```
SUMMARY = "JSON Matching Expressions"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py"
AUTHOR = "James Saryerwinnie <js@jamesls.com>"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE.txt;md5=2683790f5fabb41a3f75b70558799eb4"

SRC_URI = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/56/3f325b1eef9791759784aa5046a8f6a1aff8f7c898a2e34506771d3b99d8/jmespath-0.10.0.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "65bdcb5fa5bcf1cc710ffa508e78e408"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "b85d0567b8666149a93172712e68920734333c0ce7e89b78b3e987f71e5ed4f9"

S = "${WORKDIR}/jmespath-0.10.0"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = ""

inherit setuptools3
```

**python3-s3transfer_0.4.2.bb:**

```
SUMMARY = "An Amazon S3 Transfer Manager"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/boto/s3transfer"
AUTHOR = "Amazon Web Services <kyknapp1@gmail.com>"
LICENSE = "Apache-2.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE.txt;md5=b1e01b26bacfc2232046c90a330332b3"

SRC_URI = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/90/f467e516a845cf378d85f0a51913c642e31e2570eb64b352c4dc4c6cbfc7/s3transfer-0.4.2.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "a6771f1bbff440e3c7f550357c3e5ee1"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "cb022f4b16551edebbb31a377d3f09600dbada7363d8c5db7976e7f47732e1b2"

S = "${WORKDIR}/s3transfer-0.4.2"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = ""

inherit setuptools3
```

boto3 has RDEPENDS on botocore, so adding python3-boto3 to **IMAGE_INSTALL** will insure that botocore is shipped with it.

Comment: Thank you for the instructions. However it seems that I'd doing something wrong.

Comment: I have included the generated .bb recipes to a custom layer, in a package as follows:

`meta-custom/recipes-boto3/boto3pkg/python3-boto3_1.20.26.bb etc`
I have also included such layer in the bblayers.conf file list and in the local.conf file the following line: `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python3-boto3"`

However, when I bitbake my image I'm getting the following error:
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'setuptools_scm' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Any ideas on how to include setuptools_scm?